# EXCEL. How do i find all the rows matching the values on a different row n a different file?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two .xls files. One of the files has a column named "customer id" witch contains about 700 8 digit values such as 11557096. The other file has a column named "requested for" that includes about 2000 values that are the customer id plus his / her name such as 11557096 - John Doe. I would like to find all the rows on the second file that match the customer id's on from the "customer id" column on the "requested for" column.

Comment: [1st start with this, to find data in a different sheet.](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Find%20Data%20in%20other%20Sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple filter example you can start with.

The set up

[image: Set up]

[image: The code]

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, FiltRng As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 2))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Rng.AutoFilter 1, Range("D1")
    Set FiltRng = Rng.Offset(1)
    FiltRng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0
End Sub
```

The Filter result
[image: Filt result]

Paste to next sheet.

[image]

[The Sample Workbook](http://nebula.wsimg.com/ff03abe2fc57033836105815b5727abf?AccessKeyId=21C1C50B7677872F602F&disposition=0&alloworigin=1)

Once you have that going then you can work on different sheets and different workbooks.